# Jsoup http error fetching url

Tags: android, jsoup

I just download the latest version of jsoup(1.7.1) and follow the official code(changed the url). Then i got **"http error fetching url"**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        loadData();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i("error",e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void loadData() throws IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://forum.mtr.com.hk/search.php?station=30&cat=&x=25&y=2").get();
    String title = doc.title();
    Log.i("title",title);
}}
```

What's the problem of my code? It seems the error just happend in Android Project since i do the same thing in a Java Project that works fine.

**Notes:
- I haved added the Internet permission**

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem. Could be that your device connection is too slow and the connect() function times-out too soon, or maybe it is failing with some harmless HTTP error status. Also, my Jsoup connection worked for most pages, but for some I was getting "HTTP error fetching URL. Status=307". Turns out this is really a redirect request from the web server, to another URL. I solved all these problems with the following code:

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect(sUrl).
        timeout(5000).ignoreHttpErrors(true).followRedirects(true).execute();
if (res.statusCode() == 307) {
    String sNewUrl = res.header("Location");
    if (sNewUrl != null && sNewUrl.length() > 7)
        sUrl = sNewUrl;
    res = Jsoup.connect(sUrl).
            timeout(5000).execute();
}
Document doc = res.parse();
```

Hope this helps, or at least inspires you to try a few more settings before calling get() or execute().

Greg

Answer (score 0):

You should try this , it's work...

Set the user-agent header:

```
.userAgent("Mozilla")
```

Example

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("YOUR_URL").userAgent("Mozilla").get();
Elements elements = document.select("span.hidden-text");
for (Element element : elements) {
  System.out.println(element.text());
}
```